# Decode utf-8 email attachment filename in python?

Tags: python, email, utf-8

I got an email with an attachment name that looks like:

```
=?UTF-8?b?cmVhbF9hdHRhY2htZW50X25hbWUueGxz?=
```

However if I look at the raw file in Gmail, it shows up as follows:

```
------=_Part_1264195_253682143.1529181492460
Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="real_attachment_name.xls"


------=_Part_1264195_253682143.1529181492460--
```

How can I get to the real attachment name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because email was not envisioned with utf-8 support, so it's been sort of bodged in. What's going on here is that the `Content-Transfer-Encoding` header tells you that you've got some `base64` stuff going on, and you need to decode the filename as follows:

```
for part in mail.walk():
    if part.get_content_maintype() == 'multipart' or part.get('Content-Disposition') is None:
        continue

    filename = part.get_filename()

    # Find non-ascii filenames and decode

    transfer_encoding = part.get_all('Content-Transfer-Encoding')
    if transfer_encoding and transfer_encoding[0] == 'base64':
        filename_parts = filename.split('?')
        filename = base64.b64decode(filename_parts[3]).decode(filename_parts[1])
```

Comment: So, you don't actually have any question? What's the point for this then?

Comment: @Eypros It was a problem I had and solved, I decided to add the question and answer at the same time to help others: https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer :-)